# Adding a column to multiple .csv files with the file name as you combine those .csv files into a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have 50 .csv files with over 188k rows combined that I would need to add the file name to so that I am able to track which file it came from. I have included the code I am using below which is able to combine the files into a single df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        df=df.append(pd.read_csv(file), ignore_index=True)
df.head()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Instead of appending directly the result of the `read_csv()`, store it and add a new column with the file name

```
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        df_new = pd.read_csv(file)
        df_new['from_file'] = file
        df = df.append(df_new, ignore_index=True)
```

Also if your `file` variable is actually the whole path to the file, you can use `os.path.basename(file)` which return the name of the file only, without the path.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the code. Much appreciated.